# Linq, Select the latest entry for each service

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following table:

```
public class ServiceStatusHistory
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Forenkey to service
    [Required]
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ServiceStatus Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Messages { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //Time Logged in the db
    public DateTime time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    //Time the service last called the update method on the client
    public DateTime LastUpdateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to do a linq query that will.

Give me a list of ServiceStatusHistory Objects, for each service ID that there is in the db and only the latest(biggest time) one(for that service) where enabled = true.

The reason that this is complicated is that, there will be multiple entries in the table for each service. So a service with Id 4 could have 100 entries in here. and there will be multiple services.

here is my attempt:

```
 using (var db = new EFDbContext())
            {
                var result = (from x in db.ServiceStatusHistory
                              where x.Service.Enabled == true
                              select x).FirstOrDefault();

                list =  result.toString();
            }
```

But I realised my query will only return one object not a list of them?

Comment: Whats property define if the ServiceStatus is the last or the first?

Comment: I would assume you need to to order by time desc.

Answer (score 3):

You could group by the service id and then select the last of the groupings.

```
using (var db = new EFDbContext())
{
    var results = d.ServiceStatusHistory.Where(h => h.Service.Enabled)
                                        .OrderByDescending(h => h.time )
                                        .GroupBy(h => h.Service.Id)
                                        .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault()); 
}
```

The `OrderByDescending` will give you the proper ordering for the `FirstOrDefault`. `GroupBy` preserves the ordering of the elements passed.

Results will be an `IEnumerable<ServiceStatusHistory>` where you will have no repeated `Service` based on the `Id` property of the class. Change the `OrderByDescending` if your "last" has a specific meaning.

**Edit:** To eagerly include an object, you can use the [`Include` extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method:

```
d.ServiceStatusHistory.Include(h => h.Service)
```

Comment: I think It works :) but wow that query takes LONG to execute. Currently I only have 1 row in my db and it takes 8 seconds. i5 with ssd

Comment: If you only have one rows and it takes 8 seconds, it is definitely not a problem on the query itself.

Comment: What would cause it to take so long then? Surely it will only degrade as entries are added to the table?

Comment: It seemed to speed up when I added more. Thanks

Comment: @Zapnologica It's hard to figure without profiling. Adding indexes can help for large dataset (especially for the Grouping and Ordering part). But in all cases, 1 row is always almost instantaneous since all the steps iterates on only one row.

Comment: Just an error I realised, when I try and access service it is null. Now I thought this was cause of the lazy loading so I removed the `virtual` element from my model but it is still null. Why would this be?

Comment: @Zapnologica Add an `.Include(h => h.Service)` before the `Where`. It should eagerly join and include the `Service`.

Comment: Should I keep the virtual keyword infront of service? I tried adding that and it gives me an error.  `cannot convert lamnda expression to type string as it is not a delegate type`

Answer (score 0):

**You can try change to this:**

```
  (from x in db.ServiceStatusHistory
                                  where x.Service.Enabled == true
                                  select x).Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
(from x in db.ServiceStatusHistory
                                  where x.Service.Enabled == true
                                  select x).OrderBydescending(x => x.yourfeild).Top(1);
```

Comment: Thats only going to return one object? isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.ServiceStatusHistory
    .Where(x => x.Status.Enabled)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Service)
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.time).First());
```

Comment: when I do this Query, and I try access my service in the results, Service is null. Why would this be?

Comment: Sounds like your entities might not be set up quite as you'd intended. What does `db.ServiceStatusHistory.First().Service` get you? How about `db.Services.First()`?

Comment: You mentioned above removing the `virtual` modifier from Service. Is that still removed? It needs to be kept in.